# iPhone - MPMoviePlayerController identify when stopped playing and when started

Tags: iphone, mpmovieplayercontroller

In my app, i'm using MPMoviePlayerController to play a streaming video from my server.
I'm hiding the controls and have my own button to indicate whether the player is playing, paused or stopped.
I want to enable/disable the buttons depending on the state of streaming.

I'm using following code to initiate the player:

```
self.avPlayer = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc] initWithContentURL:[NSURL URLWithString:audioURL]];
[self.avPlayer.moviePlayer setShouldAutoplay:YES];
[self.avPlayer.moviePlayer prepareToPlay];
[[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self selector:@selector(moviePlayerPlayStateChanged:) name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackStateDidChangeNotification object:nil];
```

When the play starts, i'm getting the notification. But if due to some reason, wifi is slow or not available, player might be streaming and I'm not getting any notification.
Why am I not getting notification when the video is streaming?

Also when the video is streaming in middle, the player stops and throws "finished" notification. How to prevent it from stopping during streaming.....

Comment: IS this happening because of connection problems?

Comment: Yes Nicolas, its happening due to connection problems.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Before anything else, I think you should specify the movieSourceType property:

`self.avPlayer.moviePlayer.movieSourceType = MPMovieSourceTypeStreaming;`

Now, about the notifications,

- First, why not check the `playbackState` property before and after to see why the notification was called, when and if it gets called.
- Maybe even an more reliable indicator, since these appear to be connection problems, is to handle the `MPMoviePlayerLoadStateDidChangeNotification` and check the [loadState](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/mediaplayer/reference/MPMoviePlayerController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006953-CH3-SW71) property (like the notification for PlaybackStateChanged there is no userinfo dictionary so you have to read it through the `loadState` property).
- Finally, for the `MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification` getting thrown during streaming I'm guessing there was some error, since other options would be the movie reached the end or the user stopped the movie himself. Again, you can check to see why the notification was called by reading the `MPMovieFinishReason` constant that gets passed as a key in the userinfo dictionary parameter of the notification.

Comment: By setting the movieSourceType, one problem is fixed. That is to continue playing when network comes back. When network goes out, I'm getting notifications for load state only. And that too its "MPMovieLoadStateUnknown".

Comment: Ok, that's not bad. At least something was worked out for now. We'll get there ;) MPMoviePlayerController is not a particular bug prone API, but it has its issues, I'll admit. Anyway, did you notice any change in the playback state notifications? What about that finished notification in the middle of streaming, did you get the cause from the userinfo dictionary?

Comment: Play back state notifications are raised when user pauses or plays or stops either by touching controls or by code. I'm not getting finished notification. Only thing left now is that, when its streaming, i'm not getting any notification to turn the play button to pause/stop.